# Android switching to multiple layouts

Tags: android

This is my code:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.get_started1);

        mNextBtn1 = findViewById(R.id.getStartedBtn);

        mNextBtn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                setContentView(R.layout.get_started2);
                mNextBtn2 = findViewById(R.id.button2);
            }
        });

        mNextBtn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                setContentView(R.layout.get_started3);
            }
        });


    }
```

I am getting this error:

```
Process: com.example.storefrontapp, PID: 32160
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.storefrontapp/com.example.storefrontapp.Get_Started}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2913)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048)
```

What I am trying to achieve is to change layouts when button click. I want to show 1 field at a time as the user clicks next? For example, first user sees only Name TextField and click next to see Address TextField etc..Kinda like a registration page but with 1 field at a time.

I am creating 1 activity that points to multiple layouts. I can have Layout1, Layout2 Layout3 etc. Next button on Layout1 takes user to Layout2 and so on.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move your `mNextBtn2.setOnClickListener()` call into the click listener for `mNextBtn1`:

```
mNextBtn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        setContentView(R.layout.get_started2);
        mNextBtn2 = findViewById(R.id.button2);

        mNextBtn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                setContentView(R.layout.get_started3);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

The way you have it now, your app will still try to set the click listener for `mNextBtn2` immediately. Since the button is `null` until the user taps `mNextBtn1`, this will throw an exception.

---

If you're concerned about this nesting poorly, consider something like this instead. In your layout files, add the following attribute to each button you'd normally call `setOnClickListener()` for:

```
android:onClick="switchLayout"
```

Then, in your activity, create the `switchLayout` method:

```
public void switchLayout(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.getStartedBtn:
            setContentView(R.layout.get_started2)
            break;

        case R.id.button2:
            setContentView(R.layout.get_started3)
            break;

        ...
    }
}
```

Now you don't need to call `setOnClickListener()` at all; your buttons will just automatically call through to this `switchLayout()` method when you click them. And you can use the button's id to figure out which layout to swap in.

Comment: Thanks that made it work. But is there better way to do this? I have 6 layouts for this activity. This will make the code messy

Comment: @Efaz I've added a suggestion to reduce the nesting

Answer (score 0):

You are getting that error because you did not initialize your second button. You can't attach a listener before initializing.

You have two options. Either initialize your second button outside of the listener like this:

```
mNextBtn1 = findViewById(R.id.getStartedBtn);
mNextBtn2 = findViewById(R.id.button2);
```

or put your second button inside of the listener of the first button:

```
mNextBtn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                setContentView(R.layout.get_started2);
                mNextBtn2 = findViewById(R.id.button2);
mNextBtn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                setContentView(R.layout.get_started3);
            }
        });
            }
        });
```